# Haskell Yesod: How to read text from file and apply variable interpolation to its content?

Tags: haskell, markdown, interpolation, yesod

I have quite big markdown text hardcoded inside my handler function currently. To render it I use `whamlet` quasiquoter and `Text.Markdown.markdown` from `markdown` package:

```haskell
let md :: L.Text
    md = "#Some markdown stuff"
authLayout $
    [whamlet|
        <div .StaticContent>
            #{markdown def md}
        |]
```

There are some hardcoded links in the text but I'd rather use variable interpolation.
I want to put this big text into external file, read its contents (this is a markdown with placeholders), apply interpolation (final markdown to be converted into HTML) and finally output the result. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, finally I've found really simple solution.

Any quasi quoter could be easily switched to file input rather than inline text with `quoteFile` function from `Language.Haskell.TH.Quote` module<sup>[1](http://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-2.9/template-haskell-2.9.0.0/Language-Haskell-TH-Quote.html#v:quoteFile)</sup>. Let's describe in `Foundation` module following function:

```haskell
import           Language.Haskell.TH.Quote (QuasiQuoter, quoteFile)
import           Text.Shakespeare.Text     (st)

stFile :: QuasiQuoter
stFile = quoteFile st
```

Now we can use this new quasi quoter in handler modules:

```
-- file: Handler.SomeHandler.hs
import           Foundation       (stFile)
import           Text.Markdown    (markdown)
import qualified Data.Text.Lazy   as L

getSomeHandlerR :: Handler Html
getSomeHandlerR =
  do let userName = "Guest" :: Text
         -- | `interpolated` is a strict `Text`
         interpolated = [stFile|text-input.md|]
         md           = markdown def (L.fromStrict interpolated)
     defaultLayout [whamlet|<div .static-content>#{md}|]

-- file: text-input.md
# Welcome!
Hello, **#{userName}**!
```

This will produce following content:

```
<div class="static-content">
    <h1>Welcome!</h1>
    <p>Hello, <b>Guest</b>!</p>
```

That's all!

Comment: Do you have any idea how to do this if the filename is dynamic, say an argument to the handler?

Comment: @Isund, I believe there is a workaround, but I have no quick answer for you now.

Answer (score 0):

There is function called whamletFile (http://hackage.haskell.org/package/yesod-core-1.4.9.1/docs/Yesod-Core-Widget.html#v:whamletFile) that does exactly what you want, I think. See some more info at https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/developing-web-applications/9781449336868/ch05s06.html.

Comment: Yes, I use it (and `widgetFile`) a lot and I believe it gives a `widget` as a result. Though it will help with interpolation, I guess it expects a hamlet as input and will not give a possibility to apply `markdown` function to result. Also it seems that widget is a rendered HTML but `markdown` takes a lazy Text.